# Java Pair to Constructor Reference

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I've got a `List` of `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`s and I want to map over them such that the resulting object accepts the two elements in the pair as its constructor arguments via method reference. So the code semantics are something like this:

```
List<Pair<String, Object>> typeAConstructorArgs = {(a,b),(c,d) ... };
List<A> listOfAs = typeAConstructorArgs.map( A::new ).collect(Collectors.ToList());
```

As far as I know, this ^ isn't possible - so my question is, how do I avoid calling the constructor in the traditional way:

```
List<A> listOfAs = typeAConstructorArgs.map( pair -> new A(pair.getLeft(), pair.getRight() ).collect(Collectors.ToList());
```

I suppose more generally this question is 'how do you substitute collection elements into method references'; is this possible in Java, natively or otherwise? I'm pretty sure such practice is commonplace in functional languages like Scala.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: question updated

Comment: `transposability of collection elements to method references` what does this mean? I don't get it

Comment: I mean substituting the elements in a collection into the constructor respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it this way, your constructor that accepts two objects is nothing more then a `BiFunction`, so it's this in a way:

```
BiFunction<First, Second, A> f = A::new;
```

But `map` accepts a `Function` of some type, thus you could add another constructor that accepts a `Pair` as input, effectively becoming:

```
Function<Pair, A> consF = A::new // assuming there is a constructor that takes a Pair as input
```

Comment: not a bad shout by any means, my only reservation is that it binds the constructor to a collection of properties, it would be better if we could do a property-wise transposition into the constructor... but it's looking as thought that isn't an option :/

Comment: @JSmith `property-wise transposition into the constructor` I either don't know what this means or I dont understand it...

Comment: I mean take a collection `A` with elements `(a,b,c)` and put `a`,`b`, and `c` as the constructor args, rather than a single constructor arg `A`.

Comment: @JSmith you could do that via `var-args` of course, but the types would have to be the same for the type safety to work... otherwise you can still use `Object[]`, but obviously some casting would be required inside the constructor

Comment: no you couldn't - for a start var args only allows you to use one type - what if my constructor is something like `public A(int a, String b)`, and secondly what if my constructor doesn't want to use a potentially endless amount of arguments... what if the constructor is `public Person(String name, int age)`... all I want to do is take a list of `name`, `age` pairs, and map over them and turn them into `Person` objects by method-referencing the constructor using the pair as a param.

Comment: @JSmith thats valid arguments, in such a case use a lambda, I cant think of a way *other* languages would solve this

Comment: ok - thanks for your discussion :) it's by no means a _big_ inconvenience, just wondered if a solution exists.

Comment: @JSmith this is sort of expected in java-10, called *deconstruction pattern*, but it will only be available for switch statements. You can look at project amber for more details

Answer (score 0):

This would work if `A`'s constructor would accept a `Pair`. If it accepted the two elements of the pair, you'll have to call it explicitly with both of them:

```
List<A> listOfAs = 
    typeAConstructorArgs.map(p -> new A(p.getLeft(), p.getRight()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```